# How to fix Socket disconnected issue faced for AWS lambda for Sumologic?

Tags: node.js, sockets, aws-lambda, sumologic

I am facing this issue at a very heavy scale, which is impacting my lambda performance.
[image: Sumologic error found in AWS cloudwatch logs]

*INFRA USED*:
**Using on AWS-Lambda with Node.js by adding**

1. log.config with below params:

> endpoint: 'endpoint Where collector is setup',
> interval: 5000,
> sourceName: '',
> sourceCategory: '',
> hostName: 'aws/lambda,
> onError: (err) => {
> console.error('LogFailure', util.inspect(err));
> }

2. npm package version : **"sumo-logger": "^2.5.5"**
   This works fine in case of EC2 instance and is giving socket timeout in case of Lambda functions, how can we fix this issue

Tried to increase the interval from '0' to '5000', but still facing the same socket failure at a very high scale

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be from AWS Lambda Service, found one open ticket acknowledging this issue from AWS Team.

[Github Open Issue Link for Socket Issue in AWS Lambda](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3591)